# Why my UDID only 39 chars

Tags: iphone, ios7

I know that UDID have 40 chars. But when I connect my iPhone5 to iTune and check the UDID, only 39 chars shown. The UDID seperated to two lines, the first line contain 20 chars but the second line only 19 chars. 
Does anyone know what happen on my iPhone UDID?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to look up the UDID.
If you use a Mac you can do it with the following steps:

-Connect iPhone via USB

-Open Launchpad

-Others

-Systeminformation

-Hardware

-USB

-Iphone

-Serial number